# Self-Join using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, self-join

I'm trying to reproduce a SQL query containing self-joins using Hibernate. This is the SQL:

```
select cur.*
  from first ft1,
       first ft2,
       second sc1,
       second sc2,
       third thd
 where sc1.id = sc2.id
   and sc1.idFirst = ft1.id
   and sc2.idFirst = ft2.id
   and ft1.is <> ft2.id    
   and ft1.id = thd.idFirst
   and ft2.id = ?
```

I've tried using Criteria and DetachedCriteria as follows, by I'm not able to get it to work:

```
Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(Third.class);

DetachedCriteria first1Criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(First.class);
first1Criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));

DetachedCriteria first2Criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(First.class);
first2Criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
first2Criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id)); // where id is passed in from the calling method
first2Criteria.getExecutableCriteria(getSession()).list();

DetachedCriteria second1Criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Second.class);
second1Criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));

DetachedCriteria second2Criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Second.class);
second2Criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));

second1Criteria.add(Property.forName("id.id").in(second2Criteria ));
second1Criteria.add(Property.forName("id.idFirst").in(first1Criteria));
second1Criteria.add(Property.forName("id.idFirst").in(first2Criteria));

first1Criteria.add(Property.forName("id").notIn(first2Criteria));
criteria.add(Property.forName("id").in(first1Criteria));

return criteria.list();
```

No exceptions are thrown in this case, but the query isn't actually executed. I've tried a few differnt combinations along these lines, but unsuccessfully. Any help is much apreciated!

Comment: Have you called `criteria.list()` or `criteria.uniqueResult()`, whichever applies?

Comment: Yes, I have. I'll edit my post.